# Logging with facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I need to implement a facebook login, everything is ok, but i need something from the facebook account that acts like a password, I cannot used the facebook id because this everybody can know it, how do i ensure i've something unique from that facebook user??

After connecting with facebook, but the onLogin event is raised, what information do i get and this unique and confidential that only the facebook account can provide

Answer (score 0):

For logging with facebook you need to register your app/website on facebook.
You get app-id and secret key, and you will use them to login user on you application.
It will namely work in that way, that you will have the login url linking to facebook.
Then facebook authenticates you, and asks user if she/he allows you to access basic informations.
If yes, the person will be redirected to your webisite, you can decide to which url exactly.
The person will be asked for allowing your app to access her/his information only once.

If you are using PHP, I may help you more.
Please check this link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: After connecting with facebook, but the onLogin event is raised, what information do i get and this unique and confidential that only the facebook account can provide

Comment: @Noor: 
Do you want to authenticate Facebook. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: No not to authenticate facebook but i'm using a REST interface and for the time being, i'm using only the facebook id to know about the user. Any person can then just use the facebook id and send a POST request to my server and logging using the user account, how do i prevent this!!

Comment: I don't see how this will help , he obviously saw all this text on this page, as he copy and pasted it into his question in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

in javascript you can use accessToken, which others can't just come up with.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
    } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    }
});
```

As for Registration API, Facebook uses the `HMAC-SHA256 algorithm` to hash the info and only you can decrypt this using your application secret `app_secret`, so if you do not allow the client side to see your application secret the user can not change this data and send any facbook user_id as they please, so what is the problem?
there is also the `oauth_token` which I believe can be used further more if this wasn't the case.